# how to create a right sidebar in magento which will be visible only on product view page

Tags: magento

I am new to magento .
I want to create  a right sidebar on product view page such that this is visible only on product view page not on other pages.

How can I do this.Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: You must use 3 columns layout style from magento. And edit the right_col.phtml to show some code when its in product page, or some other code when out from product page.

Answer (score 2):

To have a right sidebar only on the product page you need to to a few things:

- in the admin panel set the product pages to have 2 columns with right sidebar
- create a block and template file (or just edit one that is available)
- in catalog.xml (this is in your themes's layout folder) find the handle called  and within that section find   in there you can add your block / template file.

For more info on how you can create blocks and templates see [here](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates).

Answer (score 0):

In magento almost every postion is handled by catalog.xml, (if you go the proper way) You can place any static block , in catalog.xml you will find the postioning of blocks for every page (be it category, product or home page) just you need to place the block in the right reference.